# Нужно остановить воспроизведение видео при закрытии модального окна

Tags: jquery, видео

Подскажите почему не работает скрипт. Он должен воспроизводить видео после открытия модального окна и останавливать при закрытии

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span id="pauseYoutube" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZvWiO5RXP_4?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var youtube_src = $("#myModal iframe").attr("src");
        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", youtube_src + "?autoplay=1");
        });
        $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", null);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: в примере, как минимум не подключены ни скрипты бутстрапа, ни стили

Comment: @Air, если переносишь код в сниппет, переноси так, чтобы в нем были все необходимые библиотеки подключены. Если не уверен какие библиотеки используются, лучше не делать сниппет, так как возможно ответ будет дан на твои ошибки, а не на исходный вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, если делаешь замечание, укажи на ошибку...  JQ  я вроде подключил...  Чего там не хватало?

Comment: @Air, очевидно самой библиотеки, которая показывает модальное окно.

Comment: ok..........................

Comment: Если добавлять динамически, то можно будет включать и выключать программно video.stop() . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251983/dynamically-create-a-html5-video-element-without-it-being-shown-in-the-page

Comment: Управлять видео нужно через [HTMLMediaElement.play()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play), обратите внимание на примеры, play возвращает promise. Так же на чистом js нет команды stop только pause для остановки используют `video.pause(); video.currentTime = 0;`  
Можно использовать [API Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, видимо потому, что у Вас ссылка уже с ?autoplay=1, а Вы в скрипте добавляете ещё один ?autoplay=1. Уберите из ссылки лишнее, и всё получится.

Comment: Вот работающий вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/m1ur2Lk1/